# How to display a progress over time in one horizontally stacked bar with chartjs

Tags: angular, chart.js, progress-bar, bar-chart

Is there a way to configure chartjs to visualize horizontal stacked bars like this? The use case is to display continuous data over a time period. I know that this technically is more of a progress than a chart.

[image]

I've a [stackblitz repo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-kq4up9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) but I can't visualize several data points per label and they are not displayed as one bar.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `yAxes` to `yAxes: [{ display: false, stacked: true }]` and it will work

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-nmyvzi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hi, your demo is not working

Comment: it seems to be working fine, might be some of your browser settings that block things